# CSV file upload error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I want to try the file upload in `ASP.Net MVC`, I am receiving the following error.

file error

> A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in administratorPortal.dll

file error

> The thread '' (0x21e4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in administratorPortal.dll

in my view

```
<form action="../../Controllers/patientAppointmentController.cs" method=post>
<input id="model" type="file" name="fileUpload" data-val="true" data-val-required="File is required" />
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Import" />
</form>
```

in my controller

```
public ActionResult CSVUpload(HttpPostedFileBase fileUpload)
    {
        try
        {
            Debug.Write(fileUpload.ContentLength);

            if (fileUpload.ContentLength < 0 || fileUpload == null)
            {
                Debug.Write("unable to detectFile");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Debug.Write("file error");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

there is some problem, i cant even get the file passed to the controller. i had tried many different method found on the internet, but none of them work for me.

- i had install CSVhelper

Comment: You are missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on the form

Answer (score 4):

The form appears to be pointing to the incorrect location

```
<form action="/patientAppointment/CSVUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input id="model" type="file" name="fileUpload" data-val="true" data-val-required="File is required" />
  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Import" />
</form>
```

as @Fals has pointed out, you also need to decorate the method with the `HttpPost` attribute to indicate it receives a form.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CSVUpload(HttpPostedFileBase fileUpload)
{
    try
    {
        Debug.Write(fileUpload.ContentLength);

        if (fileUpload.ContentLength < 0 || fileUpload == null)
        {
            Debug.Write("unable to detectFile");
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Debug.Write("file error");
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Don't forget about the HttpPost Attribute for the action, I can't see it above!

Comment: i still have the above error.

A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in administratorPortal.dll

Although i had followed the enctype and [HttpPost].

Is there anything else that i may have missed out?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't your form's action point to the address of the resource and not the .cs file?

Comment: Hello Irwin, what do you mean by the address of the resource?

Comment: Oh, as @Kami pointed out, your form's action seemed incorrect, notice he/she changed it to:  'action="/patientAppointment/CSVUpload" '?